# PyTorch ImageFolder vs. Custom Dataset from single folder

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I do have a image multi-classification problem, where all my images are stored in one folder and the label for each image is within its filename.

I'm new to PyTorch and was wondering why there is (as far as I know) only one method like `ImageFolder()` to build a `Dataset`?
It seems to me quite cumbersome, to restructure my images according to `ImageFolder()`, with its predifined train and test folders.

Is it a reasonable structure to have all images in one folder with their label in their filename? If so why is there no `Dataset` method like `ImageFromOneFolder()`?

I guess the way to go is making a cutom Dataset.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom dataset would work:

```
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from pathlib import Path
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms


class ImageFolderCustom(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, targ_dir, transform=None):
        self.paths = list(Path(targ_dir).glob("*.jpg"))
        self.transform = transform
        self.classes = sorted(list(set(map(self.get_label, self.paths))))
        
    @staticmethod
    def get_label(path):
        # make sure this function returns the label from the path
        return str(path.with_suffix('').name)[-1]

    def load_image(self, index):
        image_path = self.paths[index]
        return Image.open(image_path)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = self.load_image(index)
        class_name = self.get_label(self.paths[index])
        class_idx = self.classes.index(class_name)

        if self.transform:
            return self.transform(img), class_idx
        else:
            return img, class_idx


train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((64, 64)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

dataset = ImageFolderCustom(
    'path/to/data',
    transform=train_transforms
)

train_dataloader_custom = DataLoader(
    dataset=dataset,
    batch_size=4,
    shuffle=True
)

images, labels = next(iter(train_dataloader_custom))
print(labels)
```

Comment: yes, that's basically what I have so far. Thanks though. Right now I'm struggeling on how to split the dataset into a train_dataset and test_dataset and apply some transforms like RandomHorizontalFlip only to the train_dataset.

Comment: Ok ? Then why ask on Stack Overflow if you don't need an answer to the question you asked ?

Comment: Because I'm not sure whether this is good practice or not. And I'm still struggling on the train-test split and the transform for the train split